# two types of Bluemix SIGN UP page

Tags: ibm-cloud

When I click "SIGN UP" button on Bluemix top page, the link will direct me to page A below. But sometimes redirected to page B.
Is there a difference in those?

A.
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/registration/

B.
https://apps.admin.ibmcloud.com/manage/trial/bluemix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid Bluemix registration pages. Sometimes, updates to pages are rolled out gradually.